# How to run a python multiprocessing pool without closing

Tags: python, dictionary, join, multiprocessing, pool

I am trying to run multiple copies of a Bert model simultaneously.

I have a python object which holds a pool:

```
self.tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(BERT_LARGE)
self.model = BertForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained(BERT_LARGE)
self.pool = Pool(processes=max_processes,
                 initializer=pool_init, 
                 initargs=(self.model, self.tokenizer))
```

Each process in the pool copies across a Bert tokenizer and model:

```
process_model = None
process_tokenizer = None

def pool_init(m: BertForQuestionAnswering, t: BertTokenizer):
    global process_model, process_tokenizer
    process_model, process_tokenizer = m, t
```

To use the pool, I then run

```
while condition:
    answers = self.pool.map(answer_func, questions)
    condition = check_condition(answers)
```

This design is in order to avoid the large overhead of reloading the Bert model into each process each time the pool is initialized (which takes about 1.5-2 seconds per process).

**Question 1**. Is this the best way of doing this?

**Question 2**. If so, when am I supposed to call `self.pool.close()` and `self.pool.join()`? I want to `join()` before the `check_condition()` function, but I don't really ever want to `close()` the pool (unless until the `__del__()` of the object) but calling `join()` before calling `close()` gives me errors, and calling `close()` makes the pool uncallable in the future. Is pool just not meant for these kind of jobs, and I should manage an array of processes? Help...?

*Thanks*!!

Answer (score 0):

You said, "This design is in order to avoid the large overhead of reloading the Bert model into each process each time the pool is initialized (which takes about 1.5-2 seconds per process)." Your statement and the small amount of code you showed does not quite make perfect sense to me. I think it's a question of terminology.

First, I don't see where the pool is being initialized multiple times; I only see one instance of *creating* the pool:

```py
self.pool = Pool(processes=max_processes,
                 initializer=pool_init, 
                 initargs=(self.model, self.tokenizer))
```

But if you are creating the pool multiple times, you *are* in fact with your current design using the `pool_init` function to reload the Bert model into each process of the pool each time the pool is created and not avoiding what you say you are avoiding. But this can be a good thing. So I suspect we are talking about two different things. So I can only explain what is actually going on:

You are invoking the `pool.map` function potentially multiple times because of you `while condition:` loop. But, in general, you do want to avoid creating a pool multiple times if you can avoid doing so. **Now there are two reasons I can think of for using the *initializer* and *initargs* arguments to the `Pool` constructor as you are doing**:

1. **If you have read-only data items that your worker function (`answer_func` in your case) needs to access, rather than passing these items on each call to that function, it is generally cheaper to initialize global variables of each process in the pool with these data items and have your worker function just access the global variables.**
2. Certain data types, for example a `multiprocessing.Lock` instance, cannot be passed as an argument using any of the `multiprocessing.Pool` methods and need to be "passed" by using a pool initialization function.

Case 2 does not seem to apply. So if you have 100 questions and a pool size of 8, it is better to pass the model and tokenizer 8 times, once for each process in the pool, rather than 100 times, once for each question.

If you are using method `Pool.map`, which blocks until all submit tasks are complete, you can be sure that there are no processes in the pool running any tasks when that method returns. **If you will be re-executing the pool creation code, then when you terminate the `while condition:` loop you should free resources by either calling `pool.close()` followed by `pool.join()`, which will wait for the processes in the pool to terminate or you could just call `pool.terminate()`**, which just terminates all the pool processes immediately (which we know are idle at this point). If you are only creating the pool once, you really do not have to call anything; the processes in the pool are daemon processes, which will terminate when your main process terminates. But, if you will be doing further processing after you have no further need for the pool, then to free up resources sooner rather than later, you should do the previously described "cleanup."

Does this make sense?

**Additional Note**

Since `pool.map` blocks until all submit tasks complete, there is no need to call `pool.join()` just to be sure that the tasks are completed; `pool.map` will return with a list of all the return values that were returned by your worker function. `answer_func`.

Where `pool.join()` can be useful, aside from the freeing of resources I have already mentioned, is when you are issuing a one or more `pool.apply_async` method calls. This method is non-blocking and returns an `AsyncResult` instance on which you can later issue a `get` call to block for the completion of the task and get the return value. But if you are not interested in the return value(s) and just need to wait for the completion of the task(s), then as long as you will not need to submit any more tasks to the pool you simply issue a `pool.close()` followed by a `pool.join()` and at the completion of those two calls you can be sure that all of the submitted tasks have completed (possibly with exceptions).

So putting a call to `pool.terminate()` in the class's `__del__` method is a good idea for general usage.